# There is an error with unexpected token s in JSON at position 0?

Tags: javascript, json, syntax

I keep getting

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

I know that is has something to do with the data in the local storage, but I don't know how to fix it:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');

var holder = "";
for (i=0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var taskString = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    var displayTask = JSON.parse(taskString);
    console.log(displayTask);
    holder+="<tr>";
    holder+= "<td>" + displayTask[0] + "</td>";
    holder+= "<td>" + displayTask[1] + "</td>";
    holder+="</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `taskString `?

Comment: `taskString` is not valid JSON. It starts with an `s`, which isn't correct.